# Dictionary of dictionaries as values and index as keys

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, append

I need to create a dictionary (let's name it general) from dictionaries. General is a dictionary that has other dictionaries as value and index ( in order of addition ) as key.

Sample General:

```
{
1: {'DATE: ': '2021.12.03', 'TIME: ': '01:50:08', 'LAT: ': '41.1905'}, #was added first 
2: {'DATE: ': '2021.12.03', 'TIME: ': '01:50:08', 'LAT: ': '41.1905'}, #was added next (second) 
3: {'DATE: ': '2021.12.03', 'TIME: ': '01:50:08', 'LAT: ': '41.1905'}, #was added third and so on 
}
```

Sample dictionary :

```
{'DATE: ': '2021.12.03', 'TIME: ': '01:50:08', 'LAT: ': '41.1905'}
```

I have a for loop that generates the above dictionaries, and I just need a way to append those to a general with a key that will be the order by which the dictionary is appended.

Sorry if unclear, I tried my best.

Comment: Did you try writing a loop to do this? Dictionaries keep insertion order, but since dictionaries aren't an ordered data structure, order doesn't really matter or make much sense.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I don't know how to implement the counter so that every next addition gets the next key

Comment: What you're describing sounds *exactly* like a list.  Just do `general = []` and then `general.append(sample_dict)` in your loop.  The indices start at 0 and automatically increment each time you `append`.

Comment: In addition to what @Samwise said...if you *still* need a dict, you can take that list and just do: `dict(enumerate(general, 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a list rather than a dictionary if you want to preserve insertion order. Dictionaries preserve insertion order as of Python 3.6. But, this fact isn't immediately obvious to most people, making your code harder to understand, and if you're running a version of Python earlier than 3.6, you can't rely on this behavior.

So, you have two options:

1. Use a list and call `.append()` whenever you want to add to it.
2. If you *must* use a dictionary for whatever reason, something like `general[len(general) + 1] = # dictionary to append` will generate the keys you're looking for. But again, I would *seriously* suggest against this for the above mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This example assumes you want to manually enter the data:

```
general = {}
def add_to_dict():
    n = 0
    while True:
        n+=1
        date = input("Enter date: "),
        time = input("Enter time: "),
        lat = input("Enter latitude: ")
        
        general[f'{n}'] = {'DATE':date,'TIME':time,'LAT':lat}

        another = input("Enter another? Y/N: ").capitalize().strip()
        if another == 'Y':
            another = True
            continue
        else:
            print(general)
            break
add_to_dict()
```